# How do I make a landscape cover in ibooks Author?

Tags: epub, ibooks-author

I'd like to change the cover in an iBooks Author book from being a portrait to landscape. The art has already been created to be the same as a page spread and it doesn't work to cut it in half. Wondering if I need to use another software like InDesign but Ibooks seems to be much easier.

It seems like even the landscape templates have a portrait cover.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no 'mode' for covers. They just rotate based on the rotation of the device. Since in both rotations, the pages are still portrait, it probably makes most sense to design a portrait-friendly layout for the cover.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple has a [forum just for iBooks Author](https://discussions.apple.com/community/books/ibooks_author).**
[This discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20000264?searchText=landscape%20cover#20000264) has some good info on covers.

Here's the short answer to your question:

> Design the cover in some other program. Save it as a jpg or png
>   format. In iBooks Author the "Book Title" page is traditional book
>   proportions, taller than wide. So design one to look good there. You
>   can also design a square cover and upload it when you upload your book
>   through iTunes Producer. This is the one that will appear on the book
>   shelf and in the online descriptions.

In other words, **no landscape covers**.